# How can I solve the recurrence $f(n) = 3f(\frac{n}{4}) + \log(n)$?

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

The master theorem didn't work here. I tried to do the substitution method but I ended up with an additional term: $2Σ(i \cdot 3^i)$. Also I should find the solution $g(n)$ such as $f=\Theta(g)$.

Comment: This is the very first case of [the master theorem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/2823/91753). Can you tell why you cannot make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The given recurrence is: $T(n) = 3T(n/4) + \log n$

Using the substitution method, we get:

\begin{align}
T(n) &= 3^2T \left(n/4^2\right) + \log n + 3\log (n/4) \\
     &= 3^3T \left(n/4^3\right) + \log n + 3\log(n/4) + 9 \log(n/4^2)\\
\end{align}
and so on.

Can you see a pattern now?

Comment: I already found that T(n) = $log(n)*Σ3^i - 2*Σi*3^i$, the first sum is geometrical but I don't know how to calculate the second one?

Comment: The second term is an AGP - arithmetico geometric series. You can Google that and you'll find methods to calculate the summation. The trick is to multiply the summation with a term (usually the common difference) and then do some algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @ElyToy Check this [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arithmetico-geometric_series)

Answer (score 0):

I use a simpler master theorem for scholar recurrences.
Consider the general form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$. Call $c=log_ba$. Now you have 3 cases:

1. $\theta(n^c) = f(n)$ then $T(n) = \theta(f(n)log^k(n)) \text{ where }k\geq1$
2. $\theta(n^c) \gt f(n)$ then $T(n) = \theta(n^c)$
3. $\theta(n^c) \lt f(n)$ then $T(n) = \theta(f(n))$

In your exercise you have the 2nd case, so $T(n) = \theta(n^{log_43})$.

 However this method works only with simple recurrences.

Comment: But I'm not sure if f(n) verify the second case ?

Comment: You can see the plot at:
[link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logn+%3C+n+%5E(log4+3))